# create a login spinner while angular singe page application is bootstraping

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I've created a single page application using angular.

problem is that it takes a long time for it to load.

I want to present the user a spinner which indicates that the app is bein loaded.

the problem is that I want to manipulate an outside div tag with `ng-if="isAppLoading"`

I am choosing a vaule for this div inside of my angualr app model.

how can I manpiluate it?

tried using `$rootScope.isAppLoading` but that doesn't change it value...

code is below

thanks

this is my small-talkz.model.js:

```
var smallTalkzModel = angular.module('smallTalkzModel', ['ngRoute']);
smallTalkzModel.config(function($routeProvider) {

    $routeProvider
    .when('/', {
      templateUrl : 'components/login/loginView.html',
      controller  : 'loginController'
    }) 
    .when('/chat', {
      templateUrl : 'components/chat/chatView.html',
      controller  : 'chatController'
    });
  }).run(function ($rootScope) {

    // App is loading, so set isAppLoading to true and start a timer
    console.log($rootScope);
    $rootScope.isAppLoading = false;

  });;
```

this is my index.html

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
 <html>
 <head>

    <script data-require="angular.js@1.4.x" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.4.9/angular.js" data-semver="1.4.9">
    </script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.25/angular-route.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-ui-router/0.3.1/angular-ui-router.min.js"></script>

    <script src="small-talkz.model.js"></script>
 </head>
 <div ng-app="smallTalkzModel" ng-view>
 </div>

 <div class="fade-it" ng-if="isAppLoading">
        <h3>loading</h3>
        <div spinner></div>
 </div>
 </html>
```

**update:** I added this code:

```
 <div ng-app class="fade-it" ng-if="isAppLoading == false">

    <h3>loading --------> {{isAppLoading}} </h3>
    <div spinner></div>

 </div>
```

the result is the text: loading --------> {{isAppLoading}}

and I can see that angular is not active ... {{isAppLoading}} is not evaluated..

Comment: Your html file is missing <body> </body> tags btw.

Comment: try reversing the logic, show the app div only if isAppLoading is true..and you can use the css display prop set to none initially

Comment: thanks for answering.. I update my message it seems that angular is not working on the this div tag

Comment: @Matoy - I updated my answer. But you didn't listen to what I said. you need to use something that **isn't angular** when angular didn't finish loading up yet. So, using ng-if won't work. Because of that, you need to use css, and only use angular when you want to hide the loader and show the app itself.

Comment: Also, everything inside the `fade-it` element will show even before angular is loaded since the content of the `h3` is a valid regular html string. The browser will just render that before angular `$compile` function will process that and show the correct value

Answer (score 1):

Notice that you **can't use any angular logic like `ng-if` or `ng-show`** since angular didn't bootstrap yet and this is being ignored up to the point your app is running (which kind of missing the point).

You need to reverse your logic. Until your angular app is loaded, your `ng-if` won't work. So, it's better to show the loader by default, and the app only if the app is initialized.

What I do, is have the state of the loader in css already configured (so, the loader is visible, but the app itself isn't). then, when angular bootstraps my app, it adds a class using `ng-class` (I put a true condition there to make it evaluate to true no matter what). That class changes the condition to hide the loader and show the actual app (now that it's loaded already)

here's how I do it:

### html

```
<div ng-controller="mainController as main"
     class="main-app-container"
     ng-class="{'app-initiated': true}">
       <!-- APP CONTENT HERE -->
</div>
<div class="loading-logo"
     ng-class="{'app-initiated': true}">
     <div class="loading-spinner"></div>
</div>
```

Only when angular is initialized, the `ng-class` is processed. So, you don't actually need your `$rootScope.isAppLoading`.

On the `css` side, I do the following:

## scss

```
.main-app-container {
  opacity: 0;
  transition: opacity 0.5s ease;

  // shows the app
  &.app-initiated {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}

.loading-logo {
  transition: all 500ms ease;
  transition-delay: 800ms;

  // hides the loader
  &.app-initiated {
    opacity: 0;
    visibility: hidden;
    z-index: -1;
  }
}
```

ofc you can still use a variable that tells when the app is loaded already `$rootScope.isAppFinishedLoading` instead of the `true` in the html.